# Java subclass initialize with arguments of superclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm new in java (started 2 weeks ago) and I've been making some random challenges I found on internet. My current problem is that when I access to an override method in any of my subclasses (Tablet and Laptop), this use the arguments I give to my superclass (Device), even before I declared a *new object* of the class.

The code run well, doesn't have any syntax error, but clearly has a logical error, because the subclasses return the same output as the parent classes, even with different arguments, the 3 give the same output all the time. I make some test, change things, and discovered that when I call the subclasses methods, doesn't call the overwritten methods in the subclasses, always refers to the method in the parent class, and don't have the most remote idea why, the editor (I use VS Code) returns the messages with reference to the class Device, never refer to the subclasses methods.

But, when I use the method *.getClass()* and *.getSimpleName()*, refers to the subclasses, it's only with the methods that doesn't work.

The code it's:

1. I pass the arguments in a class *App*, it's where I initialize all the code and give the arguments that are my problems:

```java
public class App {

  // It's the class that run all the code, it's suppose to run "the tests"

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Device[] devices = new Device[3];
        devices[0] = new Tablet();
        devices[1] = new Laptop((byte) 3, 500,'E', 250);
        devices[2] = new Device((byte) 3, 600, 'D');
        TotalPrice answer = new TotalPrice(devices);
        answer.print_totals();

        // Output I obtain:

        // Total price of Devices: 700.0
        // Total price of Laptops: 700.0
        // Total price of Tablets: 700.0

        // Output It's supposed to obtain, if the code works:

        // Total price of Devices: 700.0
        // Total price of Laptops: 580.0
        // Total price of Tablets: 110.0

    }
}
```

2. The parent class, Device:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Device {

    // The class parent, set the values for the "devices" and calculate the cost of each 
    //  one

    static float price, basis_price = 100f;
    static byte weight, basis_weight = 1;
    static char consumption_w, basis_consumption_w = 'F';

    Device() {
        weight = basis_weight;
        price = basis_price;
        consumption_w = basis_consumption_w;
    }

    Device(byte a_weight, float a_price) {
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
        consumption_w = basis_consumption_w;
    }

    Device(byte a_weight, float a_price, char a_consumption_w) {
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
        consumption_w = a_consumption_w;
    }

    static float calc_consume_w() {

        // Calculate the wats consumed by the device and set the cost based on this

        HashMap<Character,Float> cost_w = new HashMap<Character,Float>();
        cost_w.put('A', 100f); cost_w.put('B', 80f); cost_w.put('C', 60f);
        cost_w.put('D', 50f); cost_w.put('E', 30f); cost_w.put('F', 10f);
        return cost_w.get(Character.toUpperCase(consumption_w));
    }

    public float calc_price() {

        // Calculates the total cost of the Device, based on initial price, weight and 
        // wats consumed

        float   cost_w = calc_consume_w(),
                cost_weight  =  weight > 1 && weight <= 2? 10f:
                                weight > 2 && weight <= 3? 50f:
                                weight >3 && weight <= 4? 80f:
                                weight > 4? 100f: 0;

        return price + cost_w + cost_weight;
    }
}
```

3. The first subclass and child of Device, Laptop:

```java
public class Laptop extends Device {

    // Same as Device, just a more specific Device
    // This need the argument "Hard Disk (hd)" to add more mone to the price

    static float hd, basis_hd = 250;

    Laptop () {
        hd = basis_hd;
    }

    Laptop(byte a_weight, float a_price) {
        hd = basis_hd;
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
    }
    
    Laptop(byte a_weight, float a_price, char a_consumption_w, float a_hd) {
        hd = a_hd;
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
        consumption_w = a_consumption_w;
    }

    public float calc_price() {

        // This it's suppose to be a overridden method for the original in Device
        // Make the same thing, just that add the value for Hard Disk

        float   cost_w = calc_consume_w(),
                cost_weight  =  weight > 4? 100f:
                                weight > 3? 80f:
                                weight > 2? 50f:
                                weight > 1? 10f: 0,
                cost_hd =   hd > 1000? 100f:
                            hd > 500? 50f:
                            hd > 250? 10f: 0;
        return price + cost_w + cost_weight + cost_hd;
    }
}
```

4. The second subclass and child of Device, Tablet:

```java
public class Tablet extends Device {

    // Same as Device, just add the variable ram to add more money to the price

    static float ram, basis_ram = 1;

    Tablet() {
        ram = basis_ram;
        weight = basis_weight;
    }

    Tablet(byte a_weight, float a_price) {
        ram = basis_ram;
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
    }

    Tablet(byte a_weight, float a_price, char a_consumption_w, float a_ram) {
        ram = a_ram;
        weight = a_weight;
        price = a_price;
        consumption_w = a_consumption_w;
    }

    public float calc_price() {

        // The supposed overridden method of Device,
        // Make the same, just add more value for ram

        float   cost_w = calc_consume_w(),
                cost_weight  =  weight > 4? 100:
                                weight > 3? 80:
                                weight > 2? 50:
                                weight > 1? 10: 0,
                cost_ram =  ram > 4? 50:
                            ram > 2? 25:
                            ram > 1? 5: 0;
        
        return price + cost_w + cost_weight + cost_ram;
    }
}
```

5. The class that performs the output, TotalPrice:

```java
public class TotalPrice {

    // This class it's the last class to be summoned, take a list of [Device, Tablets, 
    // Laptop], created in the class App, and calculate the total amount of  the values
    // of each class. It's suppose to work with n values of devices.

    static float total_devices, total_laptops, total_tablets;
    static Device[] devices;

    TotalPrice(Device[] a_devices) {
        total_devices = 0;
        total_laptops = 0;
        total_tablets = 0;
        devices = a_devices;
    }

    public void print_totals() {

        // This method iterate over the list of devices and add the total price of each 
        // one to the correspondent variable, the one that gonna be printed

        for (int count = 0; count < devices.length; ++count) {
            String name = devices[count].getClass().getSimpleName();
            switch (name) {
                case "Device": total_devices += devices[count].calc_price(); break;
                case "Laptop": total_laptops += devices[count].calc_price(); break;
                case "Tablet": total_tablets += devices[count].calc_price(); break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Total price of Devices: " + total_devices + "\n" +
                            "Total price of Laptops: " + total_laptops + "\n" +
                            "Total price of Tablets: " + total_tablets);
    }
}
```

I searched here in StackOverflow and read various things about polymorphism and inheritance, but didn't found any specific solution, and the remote things i found doesn't work. I think that the error it's for the way I declared things or some memory management thing in java, I don't know yet, I'm a newbie.

The challenge indicate that need to work with that structure and all that classes, I didn't choose it. *My Sin* it's the code inside, not the variables or the classes that are defined, even how the class `App` it's written, each one of this are indicated in a *Class Diagram* and the explanation of the challenge, I wanted to do it because I never worked with UML Diagram in OOP and want to give it a try coding one.

**Extra**

Here is a "test not a real test" i made to see if the problem was with the classes itself or something like that, and discover the classes work individually, when each one it's declared on his own variable, and there isn't other related class in the method.

Here its an external class where I summon each class and try to see another approach to the problem.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float   device_cost = test_device(),
                tablet_cost = test_tablet(),
                laptop_cost = test_laptop();

        System.out.println( "Device: " + device_cost + "\n" +
                            "Tablet: " + tablet_cost + "\n" +
                            "Laptop: " + laptop_cost + "\n");
        without_father();
        all_at_once();
        
       // Outputs are:

       // Device: 700.0
       // Tablet: 110.0
       // Laptop: 580.0
           
       // Tablet without father: 580.0
       // Laptop without father: 580.0
           
       // Device in group: 580.0
       // Tablet in group: 580.0
       // Laptop in group: 580.0
    }

    static float test_device() {
        Device test_device = new Device((byte) 3, 600, 'D');
        return test_device.calc_price();
    }

    static float test_tablet() {
        Tablet test_tablet = new Tablet();
        return test_tablet.calc_price();
    }

    static float test_laptop() {
        Laptop test_laptop = new Laptop((byte) 3, 500,'E', 250);
        return test_laptop.calc_price();
    }

    static void without_father() {
        Tablet test_tablet = new Tablet();
        Laptop test_laptop = new Laptop((byte) 3, 500,'E', 250);
        System.out.println( "Tablet without father: " + test_tablet.calc_price() + "\n" +
                            "Laptop without father: " + test_laptop.calc_price() + "\n");

    }

    static void all_at_once() {
        Device test_device = new Device((byte) 3, 600, 'D');
        Tablet test_tablet = new Tablet();
        Laptop test_laptop = new Laptop((byte) 3, 500,'E', 250);
        
        System.out.println( "Device in group: " + test_device.calc_price() + "\n" +
                            "Tablet in group: " + test_tablet.calc_price() + "\n" +
                            "Laptop in group: " + test_laptop.calc_price() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You never invoke the super class constructor in any of your sub-class constructors - that is likely not what you want.

Comment: It looks like the overridden method will be being called, but the values you’ve given the subtypes don’t add anything to the price.  Eg, Tablet by default has ram 1, but the price only increases for ram GREATER than 1.  Likewise for laptop, you have `new Laptop((byte) 3, 500,'E', 250);` so hd = 250, but again for the price calculation you have `hd > 250? 10f: 0;`, so the added price of the 250 HD is 0.   So learn to use VS Code, especially breakpoints and stepping through the code, is a great help.

Comment: Incidentally, Good on you for learning Java and OOP.  Two things: first naming conventions are VERY important (eg `calcPrice` not `calc_price`). Second, one central idea is polymorphism.  For example, printTotals does not need to know what type each device is - in fact, it is BAD practice for it to check (since it hinders adding extra types in future), so the loop in that method can be rewritten to `int sum=0;  for (int count = 0; count < devices.length; ++count) {  sum += devices[count].calc_price(); }`

Comment: I know how to use breakpoints, as i said, i don't come here after 5 minutes of trying. The price increase as expected, i test it in different files, each one in an independent test, and the results are the same as the answer in the challenge, it's works. The output in my editor, with the example **new Laptop((byte) 3, 500, 'E', 250);** give me 580, but in when try to invoque in the array, give 700 (same as other 2), and always summon the method **Device.calc_price()**.

Comment: On the other hand, i'm suppose to solve the challenge with a given structure, i can't add more methods than those established in the structure, i don't like how that skeleton it's made. So, don't know where put the filter for each total. In fact, i thought that putting that in the **Constructor** was a bad practice, so i don't know where put that step.

Comment: I think you problem is caused by using `static` fields.  Having static fields will cause all instances to have the same values.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Good catch - and also the `static` method.

Comment: @ScaryWombat **YESSS** you're my hero. I didn't declared as static at first 'cause i have an error when summon **.calc_consume_w()** because of the variable **consumption_w**, said that need to be static. But tried again, changing the modifier for **.calc_consume_w()** to public, and that resolve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

I resolved the problem thanks to @ScaryWombat user in the comments of question. So the problem was in how i declared 2 things:

1. The variables, when declared **static**, were used by all the classes. So, i declared as **protected** in the **class Device** and as **private** in all the other classes.
2. The method **calc_consume_w** has the same problem, because i declared as **static**, so i change it to **public**.

This two changes resolved the problem, the **class App** stay the same.

The new code:

- **class Device**

  ```java
  public class Device {

      protected float price, basis_price = 100f;
      protected byte weight, basis_weight = 1;
      protected char consumption_w, basis_consumption_w = 'F';

      // ...

      public float calc_consume_w() {
          HashMap<Character,Float> cost_w = new HashMap<Character,Float>();
          cost_w.put('A', 100f); cost_w.put('B', 80f); cost_w.put('C', 60f);
          cost_w.put('D', 50f); cost_w.put('E', 30f); cost_w.put('F', 10f);
          return cost_w.get(Character.toUpperCase(consumption_w));
      }

      // ...
  }
  ```
- class Tablet:

  ```java
  public class Tablet extends Device {

      private float ram, basis_ram = 1;

      // ...

  }
  ```
- class Laptop:

  ```java
  public class Laptop extends Device {

      private float hd, basis_hd = 250;

      // ...

  }
  ```
- class TotalPrice:

  ```java
  public class TotalPrice {

      private float total_devices, total_laptops, total_tablets;
      private Device[] devices;

      // ...

  }
  ```